# ActiveRecord default field implementations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Having trouble navigating the documentation for `ActiveRecord` in `RubyOnRails`.

Could someone point me to a place that lists defaults for SQLite or PostgreSQL?

Example: if I use a `:text` field.  How large is it by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at this link:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-character.html

It basically says you can have virtually unlimited space.

For SQLite:
http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q9